# How to configure Stackify prefix with Jetbrains Rider debug (.net core projects)

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-express, profiler, stackify

[Stackify prefix can be configured in .net core projects by adding middleware and lauching it from visual studio in IIS Express](https://docs.stackify.com/docs/prefix-using-with-asp-net-corekestrel)

But I want to debug project via JetBrains Rider. I can launch project in IIS but prefix not showing any info about requests. In Visual Studio all works fine. Any advices how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Stackify Prefix seem to only support the in-process IIS Express hosting mode, while JetBrains Rider only supports out-of-process. Here's a relevant issue in the Rider bug tracker: [RIDER-22746](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-22746).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by installing StackifyHttpModule from nuget, and ensure it adds this to the apps web.config under the modules section:

```
        <system.webServer>
            <modules>
                <remove name="StackifyHttpModule_Net40" />
                <add name="StackifyHttpModule_Net40" type="StackifyHttpTracer.StackifyHttpModule,StackifyHttpTracer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=93c44ce23f2048dd" preCondition="managedHandler,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

Note this doesnt yet work with prefix v4(beta)